# With Rails 4, Model.scoped is deprecated but Model.all can't replace it

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Starting Rails 4, `Model.scoped` is now deprecated.

`DEPRECATION WARNING: Model.scoped is deprecated. Please use Model.all instead.`

But, there's a difference in`Model.scoped` and `Model.all`, that is, `scoped.scoped` returns a scope, while `all.all` runs the query.

On Rails 3:

```
> Model.scoped.scoped.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation)
=> true
```

On Rails 4:

```
> Model.all.all.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#all is deprecated. If you want to eager-load a relation, you can call #load (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).load`). If you want to get an array of records from a relation, you can call #to_a (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).to_a`).
=> false
```

There are use cases in libraries / concerns that returns `scoped` when there's a conditional to do something or nothing, like so:

```
module AmongConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def among(ids)
      return scoped if ids.blank?

      where(id: ids)
    end
  end
end
```

If you'd change this `scoped` to `all`, you'd face random problems depending where the `among` was used in the scope chain. For instance, `Model.where(some: value).among(ids)` would run the query instead of returning a scope.

What I want is an idempotent method on `ActiveRecord::Relation` that simply returns a scope.

What should I do here?

Comment: Are you sure that "`all` runs the query" stuff isn't just an artifact the console? [The source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8606a7fbe9367e9ae37ad058dd07f0dd38daf015/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb#L24) suggests that it should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders/blob/v1.0.3/lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb#L161-L169

Comment: But you're not getting that warning so you're getting the `all` from `scoping/named.rb`, right? And the `all` from `scoping/named.rb` is, AFAIK, what `Model.all` uses.

Comment: Huh? https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0/activerecord/activerecord.gemspec#L28

Comment: Hmm. You are getting that warning. Sigh, WTF big pile of confused nonsense is Rails up to now. Is it still shark week 'cuz I'm thinking that Rails4 has jumped it.

Comment: lol yeah. I just need something better than where(nil) for that.

Comment: So the problem is `.all.all` rather than just `.all`. Perhaps a shameful `is_a? ActiveRecord::Relation` check would make the pain go away. I feel dirty, I think I have to go wash my brain out with beer now.

Comment: Came up to same problem, looks like it's rails bug

Comment: @kenn Did you create an issue for this in rails' bugtracker?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12756

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It seems that `where(nil)` is a real replacement of `scoped`, which works both on Rails 3 and 4. :(

Comment: The deprecation warning says to use `load`.

Comment: it says to use `load` IF you want to eager-loading, and in any case it takes a parameter (condition), so by now `where(nil)` (or `true` or `{}` or `1`) seems to be the best replacement of `scoped`

Comment: Does not work for my case: `user.active_section.scoped.uniq(false)` works, `user.active_section.all.uniq(false)` or `user.active_section.where(nil).uniq(false)` does not.

Comment: How about rails 5?

Answer (score 25):

On Rails 4.1 (beta 1), the following works:

```
Model.all.all.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation)
=> true
```

So it appears this issue has been fixed, and in 4.1.0 `Model.scoped` has been removed altogether.

Comment: Great, thanks for the update! However if you're a gem maintainer you must continue to use `where(nil)` until 4.0.x becomes unsupported...

Comment: This is a very old thread but we are upgrading only now and must maintain support for Rails 3 and 4 as well. Is it reasonable to do something along the lines of `if ActiveRecord::VERSION::MAJOR == 3 then Model.scoped else Model.all end`?

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in one of the comments, `all` is supposed to return a scope [according to the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-all).

The docs are correct -- it does return an ActiveRecord::Relation, but you have to use a semi-colon if you want to see it in the console:

```
pry(main)> u = User.all;

pry(main)> u.class

=> ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User
```

Comment: It's irrelevant - try `User.all.all;` and you get the same warning. Unfortunately it won't be fixed until Rails 4.x or even Rails 5. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12756

Answer (score 5):

In addition to using `where(nil)` you can also call `clone` if you know that `self` is a Relation and get the identical behaviour of calling `scoped` with no args, sans the deprecation warning.

**EDIT**

I am now using this code as a drop in replacement for `scoped` since I don't like using `where(nil)` everywhere I need to get hold of the current scope:

```
     # config/initializers/scoped.rb
     class ActiveRecord::Base
       # do things the modern way and silence Rails 4 deprecation warnings
       def self.scoped(options=nil)
         options ? where(nil).apply_finder_options(options, true) : where(nil)
       end
     end
```

I don't see why the AR authors couldn't have done something similar since as the OP points out `all` and `scoped` do **not** behave the same.

Comment: You can't call `clone` on a model class. (e.g. `Model.clone`) `scoped` worked on both model classes and relations.

Comment: @kenn Yep, hence why I said 'if you know that self is a Relation' above.