# Rails 4 Creating Scopes with Application Level Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

It's possible that I was never doing this properly, but it was working in Rails 3, and now that `.scoped` is gone it no longer works.

Essentially I have a field in the `User` table who's value is used to filter almost all other data in the app. In Rails 3 I was using `current_user.field_name` in the ApplicationController and created methods that used `.scoped` that were in turn used as `before_filter` in controllers.

Now that `.scoped` is gone I need a solution and it probably makes sense to figure out the right way to do this.

**To summarize what I need to do:**

I need to get a value based on a field for the currently logged in user and then filter a bunch of models based on that value. Is this possible and what is the proper way to do it?

Comment: *created methods that used .scoped* I'm not sure I'm clear on what you were doing; can you give an example of how you were using `scoped` originally?

Comment: possible duplicate of [With Rails 4, Model.scoped is deprecated but Model.all can't replace it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198963/with-rails-4-model-scoped-is-deprecated-but-model-all-cant-replace-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
.where(nil)
```

as replacement